# Organize a project with Git related with Hostinger

Tags: git

I work with a team.

My mission is to organize our project.

We want to work on the same project and each one works in a branch related to the server (Hostinger) and can test as he wants (we need it testing online not locally).

Is that possible?

Current state everyone works with its integration and when the task validates go to the main site and copy work then paste

[image]

Comment: What you need is one or more test environments for non-production deployments; this is independent of Git or any other version-control system.

Comment: we need everyone to work with his task without deranging one else (All work online)

Comment: Yes, which is why you need multiple test environments. Git itself is distributed; each developer will have their own clone of the repository and can check out whichever branch they need for their work.

Comment: Can I do that with Hostinger? 
and each developer will have their own clone of the repository (Git)

Comment: @OmarChakroun a "clone" of a Git repo is a local copy. Everyone clones to their own machine. On a web server, if you want to, you could put multiple copies of a website on a single server as long as it can handle it. (https://..../test-bob, https://.../test-alice, etc.) You could configure the repo to deploy different user branches to the test sites if you wanted to. This is not web host specific; it's just something you could set up, I assume anywhere. Or, you could instead have just 1 single test site and merge all the branches into one branch, perhaps resetting back to `main` now and then.